# How to give customise name in SSL layer in website name?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am wondering if there is any way to give Company name in SSL layer. Check below example:

If we refer facebook website then it shows its URL as 
https://www.facebook.com

But if we refer below website then it shows company name:
https://www.odesk.com/login
(shows **oDesk Corporation [US]** in green color followed by https://www.odesk.com/login
)

Visit these website and check website URL to understand difference.

how it comes ? 
What is the process of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an Extended Validation -- or EV -- certificate. The process to obtain one is generally more long and complex than the process to get a standard SSL cert, and they cost a lot more.

For comparison, take a look at Namecheap's selection of [domain validated certificates](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/domain-validation.aspx) vs their [EV certificates](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/extended-validation.aspx). The descriptions (and prices) given there should help give a better idea of the difference.